# can not get information from a userid

Tags: user-interface, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have an user id: **503536350**,
this is the profile: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=503536350

but why when I use Graph API tool, I can not get infor from this id

I don't understand why,

(image)
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/5a987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph API returns 'false' it's usually because of privacy or visibility reasons. The most likely reason is that the user in question has disabled all Platform apps - such users can't be accessed at all via the API

Answer (score 0):

Refer this existing answers:

**[How to get the Facebook user id using the access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546677/how-to-get-the-facebook-user-id-using-the-access-token)**

**[Graph API: How to grab current user's information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006492/graph-api-how-to-grab-current-users-information)**

**[Facebook API: can I get detailed info about user's location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609781/facebook-api-can-i-get-detailed-info-about-users-location)**

Answer (score 0):

You should hit this Graph API for your information after getting Access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={access-token}
```